# Angularjs: controller init function avoid init to be called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have the following controller code:

```
applicationControllers.controller('PostsController', ['$scope', '$http', function 

($scope, $http) {
  var page = 1;

  $scope.init = function() {
    this.loadPage(page);
  }

  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    page++;
    this.loadPage(page);
  }

  $scope.previousPage = function() {
    page--;
    if (page <= 0) { page = 1 }
    this.loadPage(page);
  }

  $scope.filterByProvince = function(provinceName) {
    console.log(provinceName);
  }

  $scope.loadPage = function(page) {
    $http.get('/posts.json?page=' + page).success(function(data) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    });
  }

  $scope.init();
}]);
```

The problem is when using a ng-click directive to filterByProvince('test'), it seems the init function are also called. I want to avoid this behaviour.

Any help?

Comment: You seem to have a custom system for loading pages content... Is there a reason for you not to use ui-router, or the standard route provider in Angular? Also, your $http.get should be placed in a outside factory/service and called from within your controller.

Comment: It looks like your `init` function will get called the first time the controller is initialized, i.e., the first time you reference it in `ng-controller` or load a route that uses it. I don't see anyplace else that it would get called, and certainly not when you call `loadPage`, unless the content loaded by `loadPage` *contains* an `ng-controller` directive. Could you give more details about the order you're seeing things happen, and where and how you use this controller?

Comment: I can't recreate your issue:  http://plnkr.co/edit/v7ooXMcLICD9l8NNEqOS  The button press doesn't re-call init()

Comment: @KleberS: Let me guess: you are using `ngClick` on an `<a>`.

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes, I do. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: @KleberS.: Let me guess again: Your `<a>` has an `href` of `#`.

Comment: @ExpertSystem you right again. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, when you want to have an `<a>` element display like an `<a>` element, but used differently (e.g. as a button (by attaching some `ngClick` directive)), you should use an empty `href`:

```
<a href="" ng-click="doSomething()">Do something</a>
```

---

The problem with using `href="#"` is that it is eihter:

1. Recognized by `ngRoute` (if it is used) as a "link" to the home route (`'/'`), so even if you are in that route it gets reloaded causing the effects of the `ngClick` callback to be voided or
2. Recognized by the browser as link with an anchor tag to the same page, so clicking it causes the page to reload (again voiding any effect of the `ngClick` callback).

---

<sub>I am not sure how `ui-router` handles this, but I am not a big fan of `ui-router` - maybe someone with more experience can give some feedback.</sub>